# Why does the 'while true' loop cause an infinite loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I understand the basic concept of the 'while loop'. But I do not understand why this particular code containing 'while true' causes an infinite loop.

```py
condition = 1

while condition < 10: 
    print(condition)   
    condition += 1

while True:
    print('hello word')
```

I understand when we start with condition = 1, it is less than 10, so that is is 'true'. But when we get to condition = 11, doesn't the statement become false (as 10 is less than 11?). When I run this code, it print hello world forever until the compiler crashes. Why does it keep going? Shouldn't it stop when the condition = 11? And also, why does the print(condition) no longer show up when I do this?

Comment: that code should not be working unless you put `True` instead of `true` in your while loop condition.

Comment: Typo. `True` is the keyword.

Comment: Provided you use `True` instead of `true`, notice that you have two loops. The first one eventually terminates as you expected, then the second one loops forever.

Comment: `while condition` repeats if condition gives result `True` and `True` gives always `True`

Comment: *"(as 10 is > 11?)"* ?

Comment: You have a new loop with a new condition that is alway `True`.

Comment: you have two separated `while` loops - first loop has nothing to do with `print()` and second loop `while True` doesn't use variable `condition` which could stop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `while` loop checks its own statement (the one just after the word `while`). 
So, the first one goes on until the statement `condition<10` becomes false, and then it finishes, and the next loop starts.
The next loops does not check if the first condition becomes false, it checks if the statement `True` becomes false - which it never does!